# Working with Three-Dimensional Frequency Tables in R

Tags: r

I'm able to generate 3D frequency tables, but I'm having a hard time working with them to get the information I want.  What's the best way to approach this?

### What I Have

A data frame named ballots with columns `member`, `vote_time`, and `vote`, all strings.  The possible values in the vote column are Yes, No, Abstain, Present, and Absent.  There is exactly one row for every combination of `member` and `vote_time` values.  The vote_times are a bit random in that most dates have no votes, some have one and some have several votes.

### What I Want

A data frame with the columns `member`, `vote_date`, and `absent_ratio`.  The `absent_ratio` column would show the percentage of ballots entered by a given member on a given date that were *Absent* instead of Yes or No, etc.

### What I've Tried

Adding a `vote_date` column to the original data frame was easy enough.

```
ballots$vote_date <- as.Date(ballots$vote_time)
```

I've tried using both the built-in `table` function and the `count` function in the `plyr` package.  They are able to give me the *number* of Absent votes for a given member/date combination, but I'm not sure how to turn this into a ratio.

```
library(plyr)
daily_vote_count <- count(ballots, c('vote_date', 'name_en'))
daily_count_by_vote <- count(ballots, c('vote_date', 'vote', 'name_en'))
daily_absense_rate <- subset(daily_count_by_vote,
  name_en == daily_vote_count$name_en &
  vote_date == daily_vote_count$vote_date &
  vote == "Absent"
)$freq / daily_vote_count # DOESN'T WORK
```

The warnings point out that I'm working with objects of different lengths, but I'm unsure of how to change my approach.  Thanks for any tips you can give me.

### An Equivalent Problem

Since it was pointed out that this is difficult to advise on without any data, here's an equivalent question using `mtcars`.  *For every combination of cylinder & gear count, what percentage of cars have a fuel efficiency greater than 20 miles per gallon?*

With this command, I can count the number of cars in each group.

```
table(mtcars$mpg>20, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$gear)
```

What I can't figure out is how to calculate the right percentage.  The proportion of `TRUE` + the proportion of `FALSE` for each `cyl`/`gear` pair should add to 100%.  But prop.table() doesn't seem to return what I want.

```
prop.table(table(mtcars$mpg>20, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$gear))    # No
prop.table(table(mtcars$mpg>20, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$gear),1)  # Nope
prop.table(table(mtcars$mpg>20, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$gear),2)  # Still wrong
```

I've tried rearranging the arguments in the `table()` funtion as well, but I haven't stumbled upon the right answer yet.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, no one's likely to give a concrete answer, but I think: `as.data.frame(prop.table(table(DF$vote == "Absent", ...), ...))` or `library(dplyr); DF %>% tally(x, y, vote == "Absent") %>% group_by(x,y) %>% summarise(...)`

Comment: Please use `dput`, a built in dataset, or otherwise reproducible data for all questions of this sort. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.* Please also see the R tag description for guidance.

Comment: I added an equivalent problem with mtcars.  If you can help me solve that, I'll be able to figure out my own issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, but you need to sum over 2 margins. I'm re-arranging your example so the "vote" is at the end as in your original question:

```
> tab <- xtabs(~cyl+gear+I(mpg>20), mtcars)
> prop.table(tab, 1:2)
, , I(mpg > 20) = FALSE

   gear
cyl   3   4   5
  4 0.0 0.0 0.0
  6 0.5 0.5 1.0
  8 1.0     1.0

, , I(mpg > 20) = TRUE

   gear
cyl   3   4   5
  4 1.0 1.0 1.0
  6 0.5 0.5 0.0
  8 0.0     0.0

> prop.table(tab, 1:2)[ , , 2] # Proportion TRUE for each combo
   gear
cyl   3   4 5
  4 1.0 1.0 1
  6 0.5 0.5 0
  8 0.0 NaN 0
```

All 4 cylinder cars get over 20mpg and no 8 cylinder cars do. To get a data frame:

```
> as.data.frame.table(prop.table(tab, 1:2)[ , , 2])
  cyl gear Freq
1   4    3  1.0
2   6    3  0.5
3   8    3  0.0
4   4    4  1.0
5   6    4  0.5
6   8    4  NaN
7   4    5  1.0
8   6    5  0.0
9   8    5  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg>19, list(cyl=cyl,gear=gear), length))
```

gives you the total number of cars for each combination of cyl/gear. This:

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg>19, list(cyl=cyl,gear=gear), sum))
```

gives you the number of cars which have `mpg>19` for each combination of cyl/gear. Therefore, this:

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg>19, list(cyl=cyl,gear=gear), function(v) 100*sum(v)/length(v)))
```

gives you the cell-wise percentage of cars with a fuel efficiency greater than or equal to 20 miles per gallon.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  As with many problems, it looks like there are two good ways to solve this.

Comment: Indeed, due to the expressivity and flexibility of R, there may even be more than two appropriate solutions.